# RxJS: How to delay execution of the ELSE in RxJS.Observable.if?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an object that might or might not exist. I'm using `Observable.if` to determine what action to do based on its existence.

However, the `else` part of Observable.if seems to be running even when the object is undefined. I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'genesisHash' of undefined`

```
  console.log("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj: ", t); // prints out jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj:  undefined
  return Observable.if(
    () => !t,
    Observable.of(nodeActions.requestGenesisHashes()),
    Observable.of(
      nodeActions.treasureHunt({ 
        genesisHash: t.genesisHash // error occurs here
      })
    )
  );
```

How would I delay the call to nodeActions.treasureHunt so that it doesn't try looking at the `genesisHash` attribute on `t`?

I'm using this through redux-observable by the way. Hence using actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your then/else observable creation is not wrapped in a function, so the else observable setup code is ran when passing to the `Observable.of(...)` function. You probably need to just use regular if/else type of logic:

```js
const actions = !t ? nodeActions.requestGenesisHashes() :
  nodeActions.treasureHunt({ genesisHash: t.genesisHash });

return Observable.of(actions);
```

If you really wanted to use that method, you could just create the Observable manually:

```js
return Observable.if(
  () => !t,
  Observable.of(nodeActions.requestGenesisHashes()),
  Observable.create(obs => {
    obs.next(nodeActions.treasureHunt({ genesisHash: t.genesisHash }));
    obs.complete();
  });
);
```

That should delay the use of the `t` variable until something tries to subscribe to the observable, which will never happen.